# Save inline changes

Tags: apex, visualforce, inline-visualforce

I wanna try to save inlinechanges, this works fine so far.
But now I want to change the probability to 100 if the stage is closed won.

I add this line to my code, but it doesn't work.
IF (opp.StageName == 'Closed Won') { oppList1.Probability = 100; }

```
Public List <Opportunity> getOppList2() {
OppList1 =  [SELECT Id, Name, RecordTypeId, RecordType.Name, StageName, Amount, CloseDate, Probability FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :SelectedAccountId AND IsClosed = false ORDER BY CloseDate DESC];
RETURN OppList1;    
}


Public pageReference getOppList() {
getOppList2(); 

RETURN NULL; 
}    

Public PageReference SaveInlineListChanges() {

IF (opp.StageName == 'Closed Won') {
    oppList1.Probability = 100;
}

UPDATE OppList1;
RETURN NULL;
}


<apex:pageblock title="opp overview" id="pbOpp" mode="inlineEdit" rendered="{!SelectedAccountId!=NULL}">
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
    <apex:commandButton oncomplete="addDataTable()" action="{!SaveInlineListChanges}" value="Save" id="saveButton0" rerender="pbOpp, pbPlanBWS, pbPlanErtrag, oppAccDL, oppAccDR, pbAcc"/>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!CancelInlineListChanges}" value="Abbruch" id="cancelButton0"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageblocktable value="{!OppList2}" title="offene Verkaufschancen" var="Opp" columnsWidth="5%,15%,15%,10%,15%,5%,20%">
    <apex:column headervalue="LINK"> <apex:outputLink target="_blank" value="/{!Opp.Id}">Details</apex:outputLink> </apex:column>
    <apex:column headervalue="Name"> <apex:inputfield value="{!Opp.Name}" required="true"/> </apex:column>    
    <apex:column headervalue="Product"> <apex:inputfield value="{!Opp.RecordTypeId}" required="true"/> </apex:column>                          
    <apex:column headervalue="Amount"> <apex:inputfield value="{!Opp.Amount}" style="width:90px" required="true"/> </apex:column>
  </apex:column>         
    <apex:column headervalue="Phase"> <apex:inputfield value="{!Opp.StageName}" required="true"/> </apex:column>
    <apex:column headervalue="Probability"> <apex:inputfield value="{!Opp.Probability}" style="width:60px" required="true"/> </apex:column>          
    <apex:column headervalue="CloseDate"> <apex:inputfield value="{!Opp.CloseDate}" required="true"/> </apex:column>             
</apex:pageblocktable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Confused - You say you want Probability to be 100% yet you change the value to 0? Did you try with a value of 100?

Comment: Does that code even compile? Is `OppList1` a List of Opportunity records?

Comment: Yes, OppList1 contains opportunity records [SELECT Id, Name, RecordTypeId, RecordType.Name, StageName, Amount, CloseDate, Probability FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :SelectedAccountId AND IsClosed = false ORDER BY CloseDate DESC] At the moment if I change the stage and set the probability to 10 and save its fine, but I want if the stage set to closed won the probability should save with the value of 100. Sorry my mistake above, I changed the value to 100.

Comment: n.b. code that has three variables `oppList`, `oppList1`, and `oppList2` should be rethought -- you should be able to do this with just one list of opportunities

Comment: If `oppList1` is a List, `oppList1.Probability = 100;` should be `opp.Probability = 100;` instead. You cannot set the field value on the List object.